# How to update widget with data from Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-widget

I want to update widget with data from my `Activity` every second. I have Item which has timers and its updating by `onBind` method sending payload to it. Every time it will update data and send new (Strings, Dates, Color resources) to payload, I want to update existing Widget with these data. I should update it every second as timer goes on. (payload is sent every second) Is this possible? Because I can add my data to extras and send Intent to `AppWidgetProvider`, but I don't know how to update views in Widget with new data sent into `onReceive`. Tried this code in onUpdate function. Which should be called every 1000ms which I set in xml for widget provider - `android:updatePeriodMillis="1000"`. What is happening is Grey box on my homescreen with `Problem loading widget` text. No crashes or errors were present in logs.

RecyclerView item:

```
private fun updateWidgetTimer(text: String, color: Int){
        val int = Intent(a, WidgetProvider::class.java)
        int.apply {
            putExtra(WidgetProvider.REM_TIME, text)
            putExtra(WidgetProvider.REM_TIME_COLOR, color)
            action = AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE
        }
    }
```

AppWidgetProvider:

```
   private var time: String = ""
   private var color: Int = R.color.colorGreen
   override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context?,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager?,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray?
    ) {
        val remoteViews = RemoteViews(context?.packageName, R.layout.widget_custom_layout)
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.timer, time)
        context?.let {
            remoteViews.setTextColor(R.id.timer, ContextCompat.getColor(context, color))
        }
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            super.onReceive(context, intent)

            val extras = intent?.extras

            extras?.let { 
                time = extras.getString(REM_TIME)?:""
                color = extras.getInt(REM_TIME_COLOR)
            }

        }
```

UPDATE:
Payload is successfully send to onReceive, but as onUpdate is called, none of my widgets are updated with new data.

Example of my updated onUpdate function:

```
override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context?,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager?,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray?
    ) {

        context?.let {
            val currWidgetInstanceName = ComponentName(context, WidgetProvider::class.java)
            val widgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)

            val widgetIds = widgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(currWidgetInstanceName)

            widgetIds?.forEach {wId->
                val remoteViews = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_layout)
                remoteViews.apply {
                    //set info title
                    setTextViewText(R.id.title, title)

                    //set subtitle
                    setTextViewText(R.id.subT, subt)

                    //set info
                    setTextViewText(R.id.info, info)

                    //set rem timer
                    setTextViewText(R.id.outTimer, remTime)
                    setTextColor(R.id.outTimer, ContextCompat.getColor(context, remTimeColor))
                }

                widgetManager?.updateAppWidget(currWidgetInstanceName, remoteViews)
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: U can try workmanager.Reference are : *  https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwjljJq_juflAhWPFo8KHQu6DD8YABAAGgJzYg&ohost=www.google.com&cid=CAASE-RoAPSPAiud8K9dyGxxOTivtw8&sig=AOD64_0EmpHLukdbGB9g9PN4lE8QL5tPxw&q=&ved=2ahUKEwjr7JO_juflAhXw_XMBHUEZBYIQ0Qx6BAgOEAE&adurl=

Comment: additional links are : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI5Yyav47n5QIVjxaPCh0Lugw_EAAYASAAEgJKU_D_BwE

Comment: Tried alarm manager but it still showing Problem loading widget text

Comment: Alarm manager are very old .Try work manager .

Comment: Still cant call onUpdate function. onReceive is called as manager is calling it but onUpdate is called only as I create widget on homescreen for a first time

Comment: which onReceive method>.If u are using work manager means then it is not needed to use broadcast receiver

Answer (score 1):

From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProviderInfo

> Note: Updates requested with *updatePeriodMillis* will not be delivered
>   more than once every 30 minutes.

If you want frequent updates, you should use

> [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager?hl=en)

Use a service and update the widget, example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetUpdateService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.cancel(pending);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 1000, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: It says on 1000 in setRepeating that it will be forced up to 60000ms

Answer (score 1):

`AppWidgetProvider.onUpdate` is called by `AppWidgetProvider.onReceive`. Call `super.onReceive(context, intent)` at the end of `onReceive` method. Data will be updated before `onUpdate` will be called.

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    val extras = intent?.extras

    extras?.let { 
        time = extras.getString(REM_TIME)?:""
        color = extras.getInt(REM_TIME_COLOR)
    }

    super.onReceive(context, intent)
}
```